# Google Analytics Widget does not load at times

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

We are using Google Analytics api in our PHP code. It has a strange behavior. For some users it loads appropriately, however for some users it doesn't load the first time. The user needs to refresh the screen a couple of times for it to load. For some it never loads at all. For some it loads without any issues the first time the page loads.

When the Google Analytic widget does not load, then any content below it also does not load.

Has someone encountered this situation? Why is this behavior different for different users? You can see the screenshots on the links below.

[image]
[image]

Any solutions and directions will really help.

Comment: look inside developer console if it shows some errors

Comment: on my (developer) machine the GA widget loads without any problem, its not the same for other business users. How do I track this issue it on their system?

Comment: contact them and ask to go the same way. Let them tell you what they are seeing in their developer console

Comment: I installed Google Analytics Debugger  on my machine and I hit ctl+shift+j, what comes up is a blank console. See [screenshot1] (https://brad.tinytake.com/sf/NDIzNDUwXzIzMTIwMTM)  and [screenshot 2] (https://brad.tinytake.com/sf/NDIzNDU0XzIzMTIwMTc) - Do you think im missing something?

Comment: It seems that the console is disabled. Does anyone know if the GA console can be disabled?

Comment: watch the "Network" section in developer console to see if there any errors or empty response ocurs

Comment: RomanPerekhrest Thanks - all the tabs in the console are blank. There is no content that I can look at to trace what the issue is. So you think that the developer who built this site would have disabled any content from appearing in the developer console.

Comment: Check this - https://brad.tinytake.com/sf/NDI1MjAyXzIzMjA5Mzc

Comment: according to your last screenshot you were informed by message "Hit Ctrl + R to reload ...". You need to reload page with activated 'network' section to watch the resources that are loading. Those of them that are loaded with errors are usually red colored

Comment: im going to try this with a few of with my affected users and will let you know what comes up. Besides I have a few questions a) if you see this screenshot -  https://brad.tinytake.com/sf/NDI1NjkzXzIzMjQ3OTc it says 24.5 min, I dont think it took 24.5 minutes to load, the page, then why is the analyzer showing 24.5 minutes. b) What do the yellow, green blue, purple and grey lines refer to in this screenshot?

Comment: pay no attention to those 24.5 min and check this guide https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network instead